# Intersection of a quadric and cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

My question is drawn from Miles Reid's textbook *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry*, p. 116.

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smooth, irreducible cubic. Let $l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4 \subset S$ be disjoint lines in $S$. Then Reid claims that these lines cannot all lie on a quadric, for this would then imply that this quadric is contained in $S$ and thus contradict the irreducibility of $S.$

I don't see why this is the case and would be grateful for an explanation.

Comment: Various ideas, none of which lead anywhere... E.g. I tried intersecting with a hyperplane. Then I get a quadric and cubic curve in P^2, intersecting in 4 points. But this is not enough to imply that the cubic is contained inside the quadric.

Comment: Three disjoint lines in the smooth quadric surface satisfy the following property: if a line in $\mathbb{P^3}$ meets all of them, then it is contained in the quadric. This follows from Bezout. Three disjoint lines in the smooth cubic surface have 3 other lines which each pass through all three of them. Therefore, if the intersection of a cubic and a quadric contains 3 disjoint lines, then it contains these other 3 lines, and these 6 lines comprise the intersection. No four lines among these six lines form a disjoint set.